# Is there any value in putting subroutines in a module if they are specific to your program?

Tags: perl

I started coding in Perl a few years ago. Back then I thought to simplify my code and make it more manageable I would group subroutines together in .pm files. For example, subs related to generating a report would go into "Report.pm".

Now I'm looking back on my code and since the vast majority of my subs are program-specific, I'm wondering if there's any valid reasons to do it the way I did? The programs I write are generally ~8K lines of code and my code runs (always) on very powerful servers. Today, the concept of having a main .pl file plus 5 *.pm files just seems like more files to manage and now I'm wondering if I should have just put it all into a single .pl file?

Comment: Yes, there are reasons. They may not apply to you. This question is really too general to be answered here.

Comment: If you are dealing with non-object-oriented code, you also have the namespace pollution to think about. If you structure your code into small modules that all each do one specific task, you can reuse them more to the point within each other, and only import the things you need. In addition, it's easiert to unit-test smaller units. Having one massive .pl file sounds horrible to maintain even if the things are very specific.

Comment: @simbabque - I agree. The reasons you've stated have been beneficial over the last 2 years of maintaining the code. I guess I was never fully clear on when and why you would create a *.pm file and always wondered if I was using them "correctly".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Perl, but to some extent this is similar in every programming language.

I see three reasons to split program into multiple files: productivity, reuse (which is badly-disguised productivity, or at least it should be) and clarity.

You say that you have only program-specific code, so you don't gain any reuse (at least external). My experience is that almost always generic things are already in some library and most of the code is program specific. With the size of the program it gets more important to reuse "internally", but only you can know whether you repeat yourself.

Productivity (in a more manual sense) depends on tooling. If you can click on a function call and jump to its definition, even in a different file, or rename it everywhere and most important, prepare a distribution without manually going through all the files, you don't think about having multiple files as an extra chore. If you don't have those things, each extra files bring extra work.

Clarity - If you have everything in one file, it's much easier to create one huge monolith that depends on lot of things and after a while it is hard to change. If you split it into reasonable modules where you can test "leaf" modules independently, you will have a much easier time refactoring and changing when requirements change.